# which statuscodes trigger the error function in https module in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

In node using the `https` module, there is a `data` and `error` functions that can run when making a request. How do I know which error codes trigger what function?

So in my case, I can get one of `200,201,202,400,401,404,500`. Which ones will trigger the `data` and which will trigger `error`?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean data and error events?

Comment: yes i do mean that